# Swift2 UI Test - Wait for Element to Appear

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode-ui-testing

I want to have a test pause and wait for an element to appear on screen before proceeding.

I don't see a good way to create an expectation for this and wait using

```
public func waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(timeout: NSTimeInterval, handler: XCWaitCompletionHandler?)
```

The method to create an expectation I have been using has been

```
public func expectationForPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate, evaluatedWithObject object: AnyObject, handler: XCPredicateExpectationHandler?) -> XCTestExpectation
```

But this takes an already existing element, whereas I would like to have the test wait for an element that does not yet exist.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `expectationForPredicate(predicate: evaluatedWithObject: handler:)` you don't give an actual object, but a query to find it in the view hierarchy. So, for example, this is a valid test:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
let query = XCUIApplication().buttons["Button"]
expectationForPredicate(predicate, evaluatedWithObject: query, handler: nil)

waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(3, handler: nil)
```

Check out [UI Testing Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet#waiting-for-an-element-to-appear) and [documentation](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCTestCase.html#//api/name/expectationForPredicate:evaluatedWithObject:handler:) generated from the headers (there is no official documentation at the moment), all by Joe Masilotti.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this in an earlier version of the UI tests and it didn't work, oh well, thanks

Comment: As of Xcode 8.3 (still beta at the moment) there is a better way to do this - XCTestWaiter. I will update my answer when release rolls out. Once again thanks to [Joe Masilotti](http://stackoverflow.com/users/384110/joe-masilotti) for a great resource in the topic http://masilotti.com/xctest-waiting/

Comment: I decided to not update current answer, but posted a new one instead to keep the old one for historical reasons. Please, consider marking https://stackoverflow.com/a/47181750/2777364 as an accepted answer

Answer (score 11):

This question was asked about Swift2 but it's still a top search result in 2019 so I wanted to give an up-to-date answer.

With Xcode 9.0+ things are a bit simpler thanks to [`waitForExistence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence):

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let myButton = app.buttons["My Button"]
XCTAssertTrue(myButton.waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
sleep(1)
myButton.tap()
```

WebViews Example:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let webViewsQuery = app.webViews
let myButton = webViewsQuery.staticTexts["My Button"]
XCTAssertTrue(myButton.waitForExistence(timeout: 10))
sleep(1)
myButton.tap()
```

Comment: Why `sleep`ing, though?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this, in Swift 3

```
func wait(element: XCUIElement, duration: TimeInterval) {
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
  let _ = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)

  // We use a buffer here to avoid flakiness with Timer on CI
  waitForExpectations(timeout: duration + 0.5)
}
```

In Xcode 9, iOS 11, you can use the new API `waitForExistence`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take an already existing element. You just need to define the following predicate:

`let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists = 1")`

Then just use this predicate in your expectation. Then of course wait on your expectation.

Comment: I have an example in Objective-C, not in swift. I can include it if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 8.3 and later you can wait for expectation with a new class - `XCTWaiter`, an example test looks like this:

```
func testExample() {
  let element = // ...
  let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
  let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: predicate, object: element)

  let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
  XCTAssertEqual(.completed, result)
}
```

[Read the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctwaiter) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [onmyway133 code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279203/8483739) I came up with to extensions (Swift 3.2):

```
extension XCTestCase {
  func wait(for element: XCUIElement, timeout: TimeInterval) {
    let p = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let e = expectation(for: p, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    wait(for: [e], timeout: timeout)
  }
}

extension XCUIApplication {
  func getElement(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> XCUIElement {
    return otherElements[identifier]
  }
}
```

So on your call site you can use:

```
wait(for: app.getElement(withIdentifier: "ViewController"), timeout: 10)
```