# Is there a way to clear/refresh the accessibility hierarchy cache

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

I have a UI test that checks the value of static text element, waits a few seconds and checks again to confirm a change.  At first it wasn't working because the hierarchy was not updating.  I noticed this in the log;

Use cached accessibility hierarchy for

I've put in a workaround for this by simply adding a tap to a menu and opening/closing it so that an event is synthesized and the hierarchy is updated.

It would be better, however, if there was a way to clear the cache directly or force and update.  I haven't found one in the API.  Am I missing something?

Any ideas?

this is what I am doing;

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts["myText"].label, "Expected 1")
sleep(20)
menu.tap()
sleep(1)
menu.tap()
XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts["myText"].label, "Expected 2")
```

What I'd like to be able to do it

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts["myText"].label, "Expected 1")
sleep(20)
app.elements.refresh()
XCTAssertEqual(app.staticTexts["myText"].label, "Expected 2")
```

Comment: Can you include the code you're using? Are you using `expectationForPredicate` and `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` to do the waiting, or something else?

Comment: Having said that, I came here due to a similar problem. I'm doing myButton.tap() which moves the button on screen, and afterwards myButton mysteriously refers to a different button, perhaps due to caching magic

Comment: added code above.  In your case I think you have the opposite problem.  You tap a button which synthesizes an event and, thus, reloads the element hierarchy so the cache is cleared when you tap your button.

Answer (score 8):

In order to force an update of the accessibility hierarchy, request the `count` property for any `XCUIElementQuery`:

```
// refresh
_ = XCUIApplication().navigationBars.count

// examine
print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)
```

The above results in: "*Get number of matches for: Descendants matching type NavigationBar*" and "*Snapshot accessibility hierarchy for com.myapp*".

Comment: Thank you. I am using this helper to make it handy (done as category on XCUIElement):
[[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeAny] count];

Comment: It didn't work for me (Xcode9.3). Normally all my views are updated in the element tree except very few ones which are custom views. I guess the dev has not called some super method in some of overrides in custom view subclass which updates this elements presence in the tree. This is just a guess though. My workaround tod reliably deal with such elements is to navigate back and reopen same screen, and now the element tree reflects the actual elements on screen.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me in Xcode 10.2 (10E125):

```
import XCTest

extension XCUIApplication {
    // WORKAROUND:
    // Force XCTest to update its accessibility cache. When accessibility data
    // like NSObject.accessibility{Label|Identifier} changes, it takes a while
    // for XCTest to catch up. Calling this method causes XCTest to update its
    // accessibility cache immediately.
    func updateAccessibilityCache() {
        _ = try? snapshot()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `expectationForPredicate`, along the lines of...

```
let myText = app.staticTexts["myText"]
let waitFor = NSPredicate(format: "label = 'Expected 2'")
label.tap()
self.expectationForPredicate(waitFor, evaluatedWithObject: myText, handler: nil)
self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(2.0, handler: nil)
```

This will wait until either myText's label is 'Expected 2', or the timeout of 2 seconds is reached.

Comment: The problem is that as of Xcode 8.0 (iOS 10), XCUI will often crash if you attempt to `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` for a navigation bar (or any of its children), while navigation controller transition has not yet completed. You have to first `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` for any other UI element, such as a displayed scroll view or a button, and only then re- `XCUIElementQuery` for a navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is a problem because I'm trying to test for Facebook login, which uses `Safari controller`. It looks like Facebook has updated the UI after cache.

So you need to `wait` a bit, use the `wait` function here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42222302/1418457

```
wait(for: 2)
let _ = app.staticTexts.count
```

But the above is just workaround and very flaky. A more correct approach would be to wait for a certain element to appear, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44279203/1418457